# SQS not receiving most of the messages sent from the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've created an AWS SQS, and I'm just testing through the console by sending some messages. I was expecting to see the messages that I've sent listed under the "Received messages" title. But, to my surprise, approximately only one of every ten messages that I send seems to be received.

I test this, as shown in the screenshot, by clicking on "Poll for Messages" and then on "Send a message".

[image]

I'm bewildered by the fact that sometimes a message is actually received and displayed.

Wouldn't the expected behavior be to receive every single message I send?
Any idea on what's going on, please?

Comment: Is it a FIFO or Standard queue? Please note that viewing a message via the console is triggering `ReceiveMessages()`, which can possibly trigger the Invisibility Period for messages. So, if you just send them without polling, is the count of "Messages available" correct? Is anything else possible retrieving messages from the queue, such as an AWS Lambda function that triggers off the queue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is a Standard queue. I'll try to check if any Lambda is receiving the messages. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked message deduplication is active? There might be some deduplication by message data itself.

Or another possible reason might be some other consumer gets the message before your poll.